# Displaying large text in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I Have a requirement to show a user entered text/feedback on my Lightning component (UI) , initially i did a tool tip but it kind of truncates the text and I want to be able to show the whole text . what are my other options here in salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Tooltil is lightning help text and that should adjust item inside it automatically unless custom css is used
Did you look at the form element: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/
The question needs to have more details.